# How to search Linux man pages (e.g. with grep)

Tags: linux, grep, manpage

I'm looking for information on the `-X` option of `curl`. However, the documentation is quite lengthy and I have to scroll down for quite a long time to get to this option. Instead, I'd like to do something like

```
man curl | grep -X
```

to get the line containing "-X". (I would also do this in conjunction with the option `-A 10` to get the 10 lines after the match). However, if I try this I get

```
grep: option requires an argument -- 'X'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Any ideas on how to use `grep` together with `man`, or more generally on how to search man pages for specific lines?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/kristopolous/mansnip

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to tell grep that `-X` is not an option, but the pattern to look for:

```
man curl | grep -- '-X'
```

`--` indicates the end of options. Without it, grep thinks that `-X` is an option.

Alternatively, you can use `-e` to indicate that what follows is a pattern:

```
man curl | grep -e '-X'
```

If you want to see the complete man page but skip directly to the first occurrence of `-X`, you can use a command line option to `less`:

```
man curl | less +/-X
```

Typing <kbd>N</kbd> repeatedly then takes you to the following occurrences.

Comment: I did `man curl | grep -a 20 -- '-X'` together with the `-a 20` option to read the first 20 lines below each result. This allowed me to quickly find the documentation on the `-X` option without having to scroll down too much.

Comment: @KurtPeek: you probably mean `-A`, because `-a` simply states that a binary files should be processed as text as well.

Comment: In MacOs, I want to get doc about `find` with arg `-type`, so I input `man find | grep -- '-type'`, but return this `two pseudo-types, ``local'' and ``rdonly''.  The former matches find / -type f -exec echo {} \;`

Answer (score 10):

On most Linux systems, the default pager used by `man` is `less`.

If that is the case, you can search in a `man`page using the <kbd>/</kbd> (slash) key followed by a query (here `-X`) and finally hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. It will highlight all cases of `-X`. It is of course possible that the first "hit" is not the one you want. In that case you can hit <kbd>N</kbd> to go to the ***N**ext* hit and so browse through the entire document. In case you have jumped too far, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to jump back to the previous hit.

This is not really an answer to the question how to handle this with `grep`, but it is simply a way to efficiently search in `man`.

You can read the `man`page of `less` (`man less`) for further tricks on how to effectively use `less` to improve your experience with `man`pages.

Answer (score 4):

`man` will implicitly open in `less` if you have it installed. So maybe you could read man page for `less`.

`less` actually supports search on it's own. Just press `/` and write what you wanna search and `enter`. Use `n` to skip to next occurrence and `N` for previous.

Comment: Be careful when stating *`man` will implicitly open in `less`*. On most systems this is the case but some Linux distros might opt for another one and furthermore a user can set the `$PAGER` or `$MANPAGER` variables and alter the pager that is used.